# Images not rendering with Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, visibility

I have imported the following images into Blender using *Import > Images as Planes*. They display correctly with EEVEE

[image]

but not with Cycles:

[image]

This wasn't a problem until today, when I imported the left image. Now, however, deleting it and re-rendering with Cycles does not fix the problem. Why might this be?

**Edit:** Shader nodes below.

[image]

Comment: Show us your shader nodes as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)

Comment: @jugaadanimation I've updated the question.

Comment: I have solved the problem by creating a new file and appending the contents of the current. Perhaps I inadvertently messed up some settings in my old .blend project.